# Azure Cache - Objects stored in Session

Tags: object, caching, azure

I am planning to migrate a .Net app (SQL Server based) to Azure.  However, before I make substantial efforts in that direction, I want to ensure that there will be no bottlenecks down the road.  In the code, at a few places we simply put objects (as opposed to literal key values) in Session.  Like this:

> Session("clientlist")= _MyClientList

(where _MyClientList object encapsulates a table returned from the database or a View Model object defined in the code).

The question is, if I use Azure Caching (in Azure Cloud Services), will the caching api be able to automatically persist (serialize/deserialize) these objects across various instances?

The code works fine right now (of course, only a single instance of the server is running and most likely, the server keeps a reference alive to these in-proc objects, hence no persisting of these objects on a disk).

A related question, after launching two instances behind a load balancer, is there a way to test if everything is working fine.  My suspicion is that without load, all requests will be hitting the same instance, hence the caching may be be tested properly. True?  Sorry a bit novice in this field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you planning on deploying the application as an `Azure Website` or `Azure Cloud Service`?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, if I use Azure Caching, will the caching api be able
>   to automatically persist (serialize/deserialize) these objects across
>   various instances?

Yes, Azure Caching will do this for you (I'm using In-Role Caching in my application). However for this, you will have to use `Azure Caching Session State Provider`. This is something you would need to put in your web.config file:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

(Actually, when you enable caching in your role the above lines of code are automatically inserted. You just have to uncomment these lines).

**UPDATE**

> A related question, after launching two instances behind a load
>   balancer, is there a way to test if everything is working fine. My
>   suspicion is that without load, all requests will be hitting the same
>   instance, hence the caching may be be tested properly. True? Sorry a
>   bit novice in this field.

One thing you could do is put the name of the computer somewhere in your code (probably footer). If you're using MVC, you could do something like:

```
@System.Environment.MachineName
```

This way you can test if the requests are going on all servers or just one server and session is persisted when server is switched.

Comment: Thanks.  One more, what is the object being persisted further includes other objects.  Will these internal objects be persisted as well?  I can try to avoid this scenarios, but just asking for my own knowledge.

Comment: Simple answer is Yes. It would work exactly the same as your in-proc session.